# Function outside React class method undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I keep getting that the first function (breakValueBegins) is not defined. Why does this happen? (I´m pretty sure it should be within handleTimer´s scope). I basically want this function to run when timer reaches zero.

```
class Clock extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state ={
    breakSession:5,
    session:25,
    timer: 1500,
    isPaused:true,
    breakValue:300
}
this.handleTimer=this.handleTimer.bind(this);
}


breakValueBegins(){
let timer=this.state.timer;
this.Interval=setInterval(() => { 
         this.setState({
            breakValue: this.state.breakValue - 1, isPaused:false
          })},1000)
}

 handleTimer(evt){
      const id=evt.target.id;
      let isPaused=this.state.isPaused;
      clearInterval(this.Interval)
      this.Interval=setInterval(() => { 
        let timer=this.state.timer;
        if(timer > 0){
          this.setState({
            timer: this.state.timer - 1, isPaused:false
          })
        }if(id==="reset"){
     clearInterval(this.Interval);
     this.setState((state) => ({
      session: 25, timer:1500, breakSession:5, isPaused:true}))
        }
        if(!isPaused){
          clearInterval(this.Interval);
      this.setState((state) => ({
      isPaused:true}))
      }
if(timer===0){
breakBegins()
}},1000)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that these methods are part of a component class that isn't shown in your code. This gets into oddities of using classes in JavaScript. I recommend looking through the [handling events portion](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) of the React documentation. In your constructor, you should bind your event handler:

```
this.handleTimer = this.handleTimer.bind(this);
```

and then you should be able to successfully refer to `this.breakValueBegins()`.

This type of confusion when working with classes is one of the reasons behind the new (alpha only right now) hooks feature in React that allows avoiding class-based components.

Comment: It´s binded already. I´ll update the question with the whole code.

Comment: Then I think you just need to add “this.” to the breakValueBegins call.

Comment: It looks like you’re calling breakBegins instead of breakValueBegins.